# How to add another first level key to my dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the doubt of how to add another first level key with value to my container (dictx).

For example initially I have:

```
dictx = {
    '1': {
        'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id1_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id1_value_var5'
    }, 
}
```

And I would like to add or (append), depending if my dictx is empty or already have some values another key of first level like this:

```
dictx = {
    '1': {
        'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id1_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id1_value_var5'
    }, 
    '2': {
        'var0': 'id2_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id2_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id2_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id2_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id2_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id2_value_var5'
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: dictx[newkey] = newvalue

Comment: If I do like you advice I will get:       dictx = {
    '1': {
        'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id1_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id1_value_var5'
    }, 
    'var0': 'id2_value_var0', 
    'var1': 'id2_value_var1', 
    'var2': 'id2_value_var2', 
    'var3': 'id2_value_var3', 
    'var4': 'id2_value_var4', 
    'var5': 'id2_value_var5'
    }
}

Comment: see example below.

Answer (score 1):

```
dictx = {
    '1': {
        'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id1_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id1_value_var5'
    }, 
}

new_key = '2'
new_value = {
        'var0': 'id1_value_var0', 
        'var1': 'id1_value_var1', 
        'var2': 'id1_value_var2', 
        'var3': 'id1_value_var3', 
        'var4': 'id1_value_var4', 
        'var5': 'id1_value_var5'
    }

dictx[new_key] = new_value
```

dictx is now:

```
{'1': {'var0': 'id1_value_var0',
  'var1': 'id1_value_var1',
  'var2': 'id1_value_var2',
  'var3': 'id1_value_var3',
  'var4': 'id1_value_var4',
  'var5': 'id1_value_var5'},
 '2': {'var0': 'id1_value_var0',
  'var1': 'id1_value_var1',
  'var2': 'id1_value_var2',
  'var3': 'id1_value_var3',
  'var4': 'id1_value_var4',
  'var5': 'id1_value_var5'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I see now is like this:

```
#>>> data['key1'] = {'intento1' : 'valor1'}
#>>> print(data)
#{'key1': {'intento1': 'valor1'}}
#>>> data['key2']= {'intento2': 'valor2'}
#>>> print(data)
#{'key1': {'intento1': 'valor1'}, 'key2': {'intento2': 'valor2'}}
#>>> import json
#>>> print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4, sort_keys=True))
#{
#    "key1": {
#        "intento1": "valor1"
#    },
#    "key2": {
#        "intento2": "valor2"
#    }
#}
#>>>
```